# Simple login form in JavaScript+HTML5 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm making a basic login page for my website (so people can access only the stuff they need to). The thing is, I've checked the code many times, and there seems to be no problem in it. Yet, the authentication doesn't work. The code:
HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>NSDCars5: Login</title>
<script src="script123.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style123.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="title">
<h1>Hey, there! Ready for some client-side scripting?</h1>
<h2>So am I! Login here to continue.</h2>
<h4>Or if you're a hacker kind, I'm using JavaScript to validate the form.</h4>
</div>
<div id="content">
<input type="text" id="username" />&nbsp;
<input type="password" id="password" /><br />
<button onclick="checkForPassw()"><img src="icon.png" /></button><br />
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkForUname() {
    var z = document.getElementById("password");
    if (z = "Gryffindor") {
        var z = "dxoincu3rhi"
        self.location = "\hiddencontent.html";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You think I'm that stupid!?";
    }
}

function checkForPassw() {
    var x = document.getElementById("username");
    if (x = "NSDCars5") {
        var x = "3d3huiun";
        checkForUname();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You think I'm that stupid!?";
    }
}
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: You missed a semicolon after `var z="dxoincu3rhi"`. Don't you notice that?

Comment: is your script123.js file in same folder in which your html file?

Comment: I see (at least) two problems with this code in addition to the one @stf pointed out. First, you're not taking .value of z and x, you're just getting the elements themselves. Second, you're using = instead of == for the comparison. Should be `if (x.value == "NSDCars5")` and `if (z.value == "Gryffindor")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the if statement when you are checking for the password and username and what they equal. The if statement should be `if(z=="Gryffindor")` and `if(x=="NSDCars5")`

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly! I'm still a bit new in JavaScript, I need to practice. :D

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change the scope of your function. Replace "function checkForPassw() {" with

```
this.checkForPassw = function() {
```

And user2218363 is also correct - you will need to add the == operator to compare two values.